# Why did Xml.newPullParser() returns null in Android test?

Tags: android, junit

I use Android Studio 2.0 and i am a fresher in android.
In my source code,Xml.newPullParser() it works well
But,when I input it in junit test(test directory),I found it returns null.Why did it happens?I was confused with it.

Second question,there are two directories(test and androidTest),what's the diffence between them?And I should use which one?

```
package com.ecust.ecusthelper.util.network.httpurlconnection;

import android.util.Xml;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;

public class XmlTest {

    @Test
    public void testXmlNonNull() {
        XmlPullParser pull = Xml.newPullParser();
        if (pull == null)
            Assert.fail("Why here is null");
    }
}
```

my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ecust.ecusthelper"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 2
        versionName '1.1'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4-beta2'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
    testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    ....
}
```

Comment: Can your share `junit` configuration from `build.gradle` ? Are you sure you specify a correct `testInstrumentationRunner` ?

Comment: ohh,I don't know how to use `testInstrumentationRunner`. Here is my `build.gradle`, I have use that ` unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify test runner in `defaultConfig` section of your `build.gradle`:

```
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

so it would look like this:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.ecust.ecusthelper"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 2
    versionName '1.1'
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```